# Subir ficheros con Ñ mediante phpseclib (NET_SFTP)

Tags: php, sftp, phpseclib

Estoy preparando un script que "clona" una estructura de carpetas y archivos locales a un servidor. 
Para esto estoy usando la versión 1.0 de [NET_SFTP](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/sftp/intro.html) y la verdad es que funciona todo estupendamente hasta que se encuentra con un fichero que en el nombre lleve algún carácter "raro" como tilde, comilla, una ñ etc....

No veo en su documentación por ninguna parte algo que pueda hacer para solucionarlo, así que... a ver si alguien de por aquí puede echarme una mano.

El código que trabaja bien, de momento, es este:

```
function uploadFiles($source, $target) {


  //eliminamos la contrabarra final en caso de llevarla
  $source = rtrim($source, "/");


  //webServerPath ---> ruta local en el webserver de Valencia
  $NASPath = "/path/to/deposit/files/";


  $ftpNAS = new Net_SFTP("xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx");


  if (!$ftpNAS->login(SFTP_USER, SFTP_PASS)) {
    exit('Error de conexión al FTP de la NAS');
  } 
  else { 

    if ( is_dir( $source ) ) {
      //@mkdir( $target );
      if ($target != 'temp/')
        @$ftpNAS->mkdir("$NASPath/$target");
      $d = dir( $source );
      while ( FALSE !== ( $entry = $d->read() ) ) {
        if ( $entry == '.' || $entry == '..' ) {
          continue;
        }
        $Entry = $source . '/' . $entry; 
        if ( is_dir( $Entry ) ) {
          uploadFiles( $Entry, $target . '/' . $entry );
          continue;
        }
        //copy( $Entry, $target . '/' . $entry );


        $nasModPath = str_replace("//files", "", "$NASPath/$Entry");
        if ($ftpNAS->put(utf8_encode("$nasModPath"), utf8_encode("files/$target/$entry"),NET_SFTP_LOCAL_FILE))
          echo "Subido $target/$entry<br>";
        else echo "<hr><span style='color:red'>FALLO SUBIENDO $target/$entry</span><hr>";
      }

      $d->close();
    }
    else {
      copy( $source, $target );
    }
  }
}
```

Cabe decir que, en el momento de hacer el "put", he tenido que ponerle un utf8_encode porque si no, ni siquiera crea el pdf final en el FTP. Ahora sí crea los ficheros con Ñ pero no es capaz de copiar el contenido, los deja siempre a 0 bytes.

Comment: Jamás he trabajado con esa librería, pero de siempre los nombres de archivo se llevan mal con los carácteres **UTF-8** o con los espacios. Quizás te tengas que plantear el ir renombrando los archivos según los vas recorriendo si no se encuentra otra solución.

Comment: El renombrado de ficheros no es una opción, ya que se trata de nombres y apellidos y luego el usuario final puede buscar por Ñ o Ç y tiene que poder encontrar a "Muñoz" o "Capçalera"